# How to capture application inactivity Time in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my application i want to set inactivity timeout (IdleTime).

How can i set this?

Is there any way to monitor all events in myappdelegate?

For eg i have two UIViewController classes.

when i click one control in **`UIViewController1`** or **`UIViewController2`** it should be monitored by  myappdelegate

Answer (score 1):

To monitor all user interaction events in application you can use UIWindow subclass. Implement `sendEvent:` method in it:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];
        // Process event or just reset inactivity time
}
```

To use it in your application you need to open application main xib (e.g. MainWindow.xib) and set custom type for UIWindow instance there.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably build a singleton object to monitor it.  Putting that functionality with a view or window is semantically muddy.

The class could be called "EventTracker" or something.

It's interface could be very simple:

```
-(int)secondsSinceLastActivity

-(void)resetActivityTimer

-(EventTracker *)instance
```

Anywhere in your app, you could call [EventTracker instance] to get the single object, and check time or reset the time.

This will allow for the most expandability down the line.